# Generate Random Numbers check if same value at db column's value if not loop

Tags: php

I've checked a lot of solutions regarding about looping still, can't apply to my problem. 
Still confused about looping though. I want to **generate random number** then **check** if the generated number is **equal to the content of the table column if it's the same it would generate again until it does not have the same value.**

Hope you guys help me, so here we go.

I have a table in database which called "list" it has a structure of **id** and **img**
it contains value of

**list table:**

```
id | img
 1 |  1
 2 |  2
 3 |  3
 4 |  4
```

**number.php**

```
$new_array = array();
$query = "SELECT img FROM list";
$query = mysql_query($query);
while ($query_get = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $new_array[] = $query_get[0]; //Store img values into an array
}

$rand = rand(1,5); //Generates random number 1 to 5
$search_r = array_search($rand, $new_array); //Checks if the random number has the same value to the array

while($search == "") { //Until random number gets number 5 it would stop looping
    $rand = rand(1,5);
}
echo $rand; //and echo the number 5 here.
```

Still the result is **non-stop loading screen at my browser**

Well I have this piece of code to determine if the random number and the array has the same value. But it's only good at one loop.

```
if (array_search($rand,$new_array)) {
    echo "random number has the same value inside the array" . $rand;
} else {
    echo "random number does not have the same value inside an array" . $rand;
}
```

To cut the story short, the values in my table **img is 1,2,3, and 4** and I'm **generating numbers 1 to 5**. Until the generated numbers **output 5 it would echo**. If the generated numbers get **1 to 4 it would generate again until it gets 5**.

Comment: `while($search == "") {` will loop forever if you do not define `$search` in that while.

Comment: Why don't you let mysql do the job for you? Set id as the primary key with auto increment

Comment: @Mihai, haha silly me, never realized that forgot to put _r on it.

Comment: IMHO this sounds like an inherently broken design. It won't scale - that's for sure. I'd recommend you open up another thread and tell us about what you are trying to achieve. I'm pretty sure there's a solution that does not involve looping over existing data.

Comment: use `mt_rand(1,5)`.     it "produces a better random value, and is 4 times faster than `rand()`" - W3Schools.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `do...while` loop:

```
do {
    $rand = rand(1, 5);
} while (in_array($rand, $new_array));
```

Although I'm not sure why you need to generate a random number like this. Why do you need this number?

Comment: My savior! Thanks a lot. Solving this for epic minutes now.
Well, I need this for randomized something. for image name uploads. :x

Comment: Assuming the database has like a million entries. Wouldn't it be better to check only for a single result everytime a new random string is created instead of loading all values and loop through them over and over?

Comment: @insertusernamehere: I'd just skip that and use an auto-incrementing primary key or a random string. Using `rand` for this task might become problematic.

Comment: Yeah of course I also assumed a random string. Your solution is fine - I only wonder if its not better to create a random string and than check whether this one exists. When I guess that this one is not in the database I only need to query one time for a single result. In that case I could prevent a huge database request and the skip the part of looping through all those results.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought of that rand is not a good solution for this, unfortunately I can't think of any solution beside that. Yet I might try the ideas that you guys gave to me. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function maybe useful in this scenario.

1. inside function create a random string
2. Check it in database
3. If exists then move call recursive function again
4. else return string

Comment: I believe it would help if you provide an example of the points you've listed above